# Advice on structuring a class for a pointer to one of many structs determined at runtime

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, encoding, bmp

I'm writing a bitmap (bpm) parser to practice c++ as I'm learning. However there are many different image headers over the versions, and I've hit a wall around how to approach this is a way that feels avoids many checks and is elegant. Could you please give me advice on some of the following approaches or suggest other ones?

Here are the approaches that I've thought of. The main reason I've been having trouble is I want to use `memcpy` to avoid copying each field individually. The only thing that is consistent across the structs is the first 4 bytes define the size of the header/struct.

1. Use multiple pointers in the class. Set each one to a nullptr at initialization. Then use one `reinterpret_cast` to determine which header to use when first parsing the file. From then on check for which pointer is not a nullptr to determine which one to use.
2. Use a void ptr and use `reinterpret_cast` whenever doing an operation on getting or setting values in the header. Probably not the best option but it's there.
3. Create an [ABC](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/abcs) (which I'm not sure I entirely understand). Would allow for an inheritance structure. Not sure this would work smoothly with `memcpy` because from what I understand having virtual methods will add an invisible pointer at the beginning of the struct which would break using an unmodified buffer by coping it directly into the structure. (Please tell me if I'm wrong about this).

Currently trying approach one. Here's my header file.

```cpp
#ifndef BITMAP_H_INCLUDE
#define BITMAP_H_INCLUDE

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

enum HeaderSizes
{
  File = 14,
  Core = 12,
  InfoV1 = 40,
  OS2 = 64,
  InfoV4 = 108,
  InfoV5 = 124,
};

enum InfoCompressionMethod
{
  // omitted for brevity
};

enum HalftoneAlgorithms
{
  // omitted for brevity
};

struct FileHeader
{
  // omitted for brevity, first header is always 14 bytes
};

struct CoreHeader
{
  uint32_t header_size;
  uint16_t width;
  uint16_t height;
  uint16_t planes;
  uint16_t bit_depth;
};

struct InfoV1Header
{
  uint32_t header_size;
  int32_t width;
  int32_t height;
  uint16_t planes;
  uint16_t bit_depth;
  uint32_t compression;
  uint32_t size_image;
  int32_t x_resolution;
  int32_t y_resolution;
  uint32_t color_used;
  uint32_t color_important;
};

struct OS2Header : public InfoV1Header
{
  uint16_t resolution_units;
  uint16_t reserved;
  uint16_t fill_direction;
  uint16_t halftone_algorithm;
  uint32_t halftone_param_1;
  uint32_t halftone_param_2;
  uint32_t color_encoding;
  uint32_t application_defined;
};

struct InfoV4Header : public InfoV1Header
{
  uint32_t red_mask;
  uint32_t green_mask;
  uint32_t blue_mask;
  uint32_t alpha_mask;
  uint32_t cs_type;
  uint64_t red_x;
  uint64_t red_y;
  uint64_t red_z;
  uint64_t green_x;
  uint64_t green_y;
  uint64_t green_z;
  uint64_t blue_x;
  uint64_t blue_y;
  uint64_t blue_z;
  uint32_t gamma_red;
  uint32_t gamma_green;
  uint32_t gamma_blue;
};

struct InfoV5Header : public InfoV4Header
{
  uint32_t  intent;
  uint32_t  profile_data;
  uint32_t  profile_size;
  uint32_t  reserved;
};

class Bitmap
{
  public:

    Bitmap(std::string in_path);
    ~Bitmap();
    void save(std::string out_path);

  private:

    FileHeader* file_header;

    // Info Header Options
    CoreHeader* core_header;
    OS2Header* os2_header;
    InfoV1Header* info_v1_header;
    InfoV4Header* info_v4_header;
    InfoV5Header* info_v5_header;

    void verify_file_header() const;

};

#endif /* BITMAP_H_INCLUDE */
```

Seems like the best option right now but I'm cringing at the idea of writing a bunch of methods that start with checking for nullptrs in the info headers. Hopefully I'm missing something because I don't know c++ very well.

(Currently working in c++14 but not against using 17 if it makes sense. On Linux Zorin OS 15, using gcc 7.4, with cmake 3.15.2.)

Comment: Avoid `reinterpret_cast` when possible. I don't know the format, but `std::variant<InfoV1Header, InfoV4Header, InfoV5Header>` if only one header is valid or have several `std::optional<InfoV1Header>`, `std::optional<InfoV4Header>` if each is optional (mostly equivalent to your pointer version, but without manual memory management).

Comment: I don't think you can map directly from raw image data to c++ memory layouts, as the latter has [alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment) and padding bits...

Comment: The most common format corresponds to `InfoV4Header`. This format supports 1, 4, 8, 16, 24, and 32 bit bitmaps. It will take you a while to write a parser for just this one format (in practice you should use an image library). Note that the structures are padded, so if you are reading from file in to memory, then you need `#pragma pack(push, 2)` to make the structures are packed (close it with `#pragma pack(pop)`)

Answer (score 0):

A random unrelated point, the red_x through blue_z fields in the V4 header are 32bit signed integers, and not 64bit uints as you have them above (Actually they are FXPT2DOT30 type - fixed point with 2bit integer part, 30bit decimal).

The typical way to handle this problem is to load the entire BMP file into one big lump of memory, and then just reinterpret_cast your way to the data. As you've noticed, V5 derives from V4, which derives from V1. Given that it's the size of the header that determines which type of header is in the file, you can do a poor mans dynamic cast....

```cpp
struct InfoV1Header;
struct OS2Header;
struct InfoV4Header;
struct InfoV5Header;

struct InfoV1Header
{
  uint32_t header_size;
  int32_t width;
  int32_t height;
  uint16_t planes;
  uint16_t bit_depth;
  uint32_t compression;
  uint32_t size_image;
  int32_t x_resolution;
  int32_t y_resolution;
  uint32_t color_used;
  uint32_t color_important;

  template<typename T>
  inline const T* as() const;
};

struct OS2Header : public InfoV1Header
{
  uint16_t resolution_units;
  uint16_t reserved;
  uint16_t fill_direction;
  uint16_t halftone_algorithm;
  uint32_t halftone_param_1;
  uint32_t halftone_param_2;
  uint32_t color_encoding;
  uint32_t application_defined;
};

struct InfoV4Header : public InfoV1Header
{
  uint32_t red_mask;
  uint32_t green_mask;
  uint32_t blue_mask;
  uint32_t alpha_mask;
  uint32_t cs_type;
  int32_t red_x;
  int32_t red_y;
  int32_t red_z;
  int32_t green_x;
  int32_t green_y;
  int32_t green_z;
  int32_t blue_x;
  int32_t blue_y;
  int32_t blue_z;
  uint32_t gamma_red;
  uint32_t gamma_green;
  uint32_t gamma_blue;
};

struct InfoV5Header : public InfoV4Header
{
  uint32_t  intent;
  uint32_t  profile_data;
  uint32_t  profile_size;
  uint32_t  reserved;
};

template<>
inline const OS2Header* InfoV1Header::as<OS2Header>() const
{
  return header_size == sizeof(OS2Header) ? (const OS2Header*)this : 0;
}

template<>
inline const InfoV4Header* InfoV1Header::as<InfoV4Header>() const
{
  return header_size >= sizeof(InfoV4Header) ? (const InfoV4Header*)this : 0;
}

template<>
inline const InfoV5Header* InfoV1Header::as<InfoV5Header>() const
{
  return header_size >= sizeof(InfoV5Header) ? (const InfoV5Header*)this : 0;
}
```

This then would allow you to work with the data in a slightly more manageable way than maintaining numerous pointers to different structures *(which will all be the same address - so it's not worth storing multiple times imho)*.

```
void doStuff(const InfoV1Header* v1)
{
  // do stuff with the v1 fields

  if(const OS2Header* os2 = v1->as<OS2Header>())
  {
    // do stuff with os2 fields
  }

  if(const InfoV4Header* v4 = v1->as<InfoV4Header>())
  {
    // do stuff with v4 fields
  }

  if(const InfoV5Header* v5 = v1->as<InfoV5Header>())
  {
    // do stuff with v5 fields
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I haven't really gotten into templating yet so I'll have to do some research but seems like this would be a better approach then what I came up with.